# How to handle Polymer routing in Google Appengine

Tags: google-app-engine, polymer

I'm trying to run this Polymer app (https://divshot.com/blog/web-components/building-a-qa-system-with-polymer-and-firebase/) on Google App Engine. I was able to get the first page to work by setting up the routing

```
webapp2.Route(r'/polymer', handler=project_handler.PolymerHandler, name='polymer'),
```

but when the Github oAuth successfully returns the login user back to the callback URL, the question input screen (list.html) doesn't show up. (FYI. When I run the exact same project outside of GAE, it works just fine. So I believe the issue is with my GAE routing setup.)

```
<core-header-panel>
  <div class="core-header">
    <core-toolbar>
      <div flex>Firebase Q&amp;A</div>
      <paper-menu-button halign="right">
        <paper-icon-button icon="social:person"></paper-icon-button>
        <paper-dropdown class="dropdown" transition="">
          <core-menu class="menu">
            <paper-item on-click="{{login}}" hidden?="{{!statusKnown || user}}">Login</paper-item>
            <paper-item on-click="{{logout}}" hidden?="{{!statusKnown || !user}}">Logout</paper-item>
          </core-menu>
        </paper-dropdown>
      </paper-menu-button>
      <template if="{{user}}">{{user.github.username}}</template>
    </core-toolbar>
  </div>
  <div class="content">
    <app-router>  <!-- This handles routing for Polymer app -->
      <app-route path="/" import="/app/component/questions/list.html" element="qa-list"></app-route>
      <app-route path="/app/component/questions/:id" import="/app/component/questions/view.html" element="qa-view"></app-route>
    </app-router>
  </div>
</core-header-panel>
```

Apparently this app-router isn't working.

Can you please point me to the right direction? Thanks.

Project structure

Project root
 \app\
 \app\index.html
 \app\component
 \app\component\qa.html
 \app\component\questions\list.html
 \bower_components
 \app.yaml

App.yaml

```
handlers:

- url: /components
  static_dir: bower_components

- url: /app
  static_dir: app

- url: /
  static_files: app/index\.html
  upload: app/index\.html
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the project you are trying to run seems to entirely consist of static files there's no need to define the routes in `webapp2` or use any python code at all as GAE could serve all that with some `app.yaml` settings which assuming that you have both `bower_components` and `app` folders in the root of your project in your case would be something like:

```
handlers:
- url: /bower_components
  static_dir: bower_components

- url: /app
  static_dir: app

- url: /
  static_files: app/index\.html
  upload: app/index\.html
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. I tried as you suggested but unfortunately I couldn't get it to work. Based on the Network log in the developer tool, the app doesn't even try to get this list.html file.

Comment: Could you go ahead and share the *.appspot.com link with whatever you have deployed? Also, may be add the contents of `app.yaml` in here as well.

Comment: @MihailRussu, full agreement that we need to see `app.yaml` (and `dispatch.yaml` if a multimodule app but that doesn't seem to be the case) -- the very first level of routing, after all!

Comment: It looks like you need to create a route for /app/index.html. Locally it's problably / but on the server it looks like your home is /app/index.html.

Comment: It seems to be working now after moving index.html to the project root and changed the app.yaml to
- url: /
  static_file: index.html
  upload: index.html 

I'm surprised app-router also seems to work now. I'm still unsure how this works when app.yaml and app-router point url: / to two different files (ie. \index.html and app\component\questions\list.html, respectively).